# Angular 2 HTTP call with interval via Rxjs interval operator

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

When I try to make http call like this:

```
return this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json());
```

everything is expected I have correct response without errors, but when I try to make http call with interval (via RxJS operator interval) I have an error.

My code looks:

```
   return Observable.interval(1000).map(() => {
    return this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json());
  });
```

Error:

> ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3000/node_modules/rxjs
>       Error: …, __zone_symbol__stack: "(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http:…alhost:3000/app/home/components/home.component.js", originalErr: ZoneAwareError}

Comment: What behavior are you trying to accomplish here? You just want to make an API call every second?

Answer (score 2):

You have to use [`.flatMap()`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/selectmany.md) and `IntervalObservable` to get data from another `Observable`:

```
return IntervalObservable
    .create(1000)
    .flatMap(() => {
        return this.http.get(this.url).map(res => res.json());
     });
```

Comment: But now I have an error:
`EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:1:14 caused by: Observable_1.Observable.interval(...).flatMap is not a function`

Comment: Updated my answer - API seems to have changed, you need to use `IntervalObservable` nowadays.

Comment: What does mean `IntervalObservable` ? I should import it or declare?

Comment: Import it like Observable

Comment: I have done it, but I still have error: `EXCEPTION: Error in ./AppComponent class AppComponent - inline template:1:14 caused by: IntervalObservable_1.IntervalObservable.create(...).flatMap is not a function`.
Should I import flatMap manually?

Comment: Possibly, if you don't Import the whole rxjs namespace

Comment: I have imported the whole rxjs, but error still unfortunately exist.

Comment: Which version of rxjs are you using?

Comment: I use 5.0.1 version

Comment: How about `selectMany` instead of `flatMap`?

Comment: I don't have selectMany method in my version of RxJS library

Comment: Then I'm out of ideas

Comment: Thanks @rinukkusu! I have found the problem. The reason was incorrect import for Observable. But now my app works fine.